# solving microsoft edge issue with respect to request method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge, axios

- i am trying to fix microsoft edge issue.
- the problem is I am making service call through axios.
- in chrome when I do service call the request method is get where as in IE it shows options method
- providing snippet of code below

**Request URL:https://sports.com/portfolio-models?tickets=basketball
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:78.4923.89**

```
    function i() {
        return l.get("https://sports.com/portfolio-models?tickets=basketball ", {
            withCredentials: !0
        })
    }
    Object.allKeyboards(e, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
    }),
    e.createGoal = r,
    e.getProductGroupDetails = i;
    var a = n(155)
      , s = o(a)
      , l = (0,
    s["default"])()
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this: _in chrome when I do service call the request method is get where as in IE it shows options method_

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I speaking with respect to the below result in the browser ` Request URL:https://sports.com/portfolio-models?tickets=basketball
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:78.4923.89
`

Comment: i think he mean that in chrome it's a GET method but in IE it's an OPTION Method, 99% chance it's a Cross origine request problem with chrome, but i could be wrong. From where are you calling the https://sports.com/... url ?

Comment: @Rugdr but both Edge and chrome are using same js code

Comment: Can you link to a demo that shows the behavior? I'm am engineer on the Edge team, and would be more than happy to investigate.

Comment: @Sampson thanks for your reply...its a huge codebase that's the reason I posted the snippet of code where that call is happening...if you want I can post the unminified version of code from browser in a fiddle but its 13,000 lines code

Comment: @Sampson can you check whether this one working in edge https://jsfiddle.net/64bnguk9/1/ which uses axios but its not related to by codebase

Comment: @texirv I only see GET and POST verbs being used in that fiddle. Can I access the project directly to see where the OPTIONS method is being used?

Comment: @Sampson I dont have fiddle...not sure how to provide you the access or can you provide you the error I am seeing in console of edge

Comment: @Sampson I see this error ---> SEC7123: Request header authorization was not present in the Access-control-Allow-Headers list

Comment: @Sampson can you help

Comment: @texirv I'm happy to assist. Can you provide direct access to the site, or stand up a separate example that reproduces the issue? Or, open Edge's Network tab in F12, and export a .HAR of the requests/responses?